# pandas df select unique values in a column and create separate df's for each unique value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 12 months of data ( i have a date column). I want to split that dataframe into 12 dataframes based on unique value in the date column. each month the dataframe will be updated with 1 more month so need to take latest 12 months

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (particularly [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get good responses.

Comment: Look into `groupby`

Comment: Please share some sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform an operation on a DataFrame in Pandas, it does not change the original DataFrame, but rather passes a new DataFrame with changes applied as a return value. So if we do, for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('data.csv')
new_df = df[df.name == 'John']
```

*df* and *new_df* are completely different DataFrames, with *new_df* being a subset of *df*. So, to achieve what you want, you simply filter your original DataFrame by month. It's worth noting that if your date column is of type DateTime, you can use *.dt* to perform datetime-specific operations, such as:

```
df[df.dt.month == 1]
```

With this in mind, you could do something similar to (supposing your original DataFrame is called *df*):

```
monthly_array = list()
for i in range(1,13):
    monthly_array[i-1] = df[df.date.dt.month == i]
```